# Установить значение инпуту

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вот практикуюсь по JavaScript. Дали задачу - задать инпуту значение. Я думал все так-то просто, выбрать инпут по айди или другим методом и через свойство-атрибут value задать ему значение. Но дело в том, что генерация значения идет динамически через аякс, подгружает, как я понял, и когда я пытаюсь через .value вставить и пройти валидацию - пишет что не заполнено поле.

Для примера дали ссылку на страничку

https://ru.wargaming.net/shop/wot/gold/34/ (если запрещено извиняюсь, но больше примера, такого как там не видел)

Там есть поле, в котором указано кол-во (монет), выбираю я его

```
var i1= document.getElementsByClassName('form-inputtext__amount');
console.log(i1[0].value);
```

Дело в том, что `i1[0].value` возвращает `undefined`

А если я пытаюсь задать `i1[0].value = 123;` То значение устанавливается, но при нажатии кнопки - пишет что поле не заполнено

Изначально просматривая код, там даже у этого инпута нет атрибута value, по идее через Ajax все гоняется при изменении данных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно установить значение такому инпуту через JavaScript код?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, пример в jsfiddle.

Comment: мм.. не пользуюсь таким не знаю...

Comment: Ну в вопрос хотя бы добавьте html и js коды, демонстрирующие вашу проблему.

Comment: очередная школота хочет поломать танчики, расходимся пацаны)

Comment: В теории вы все правильно делаете. Просто в данном случае конкретно на данном сайте инпут реагирует именно на нажатие клавиш внутри, чтоб что-то валидировать. И конкретно на данном сайте значит нужно добавочно это сэмулировать..... а если в целом говорить про инпуты - то ваш код вполне себе рабочий

Comment: если выбираете в `inp`, то что такое `i1[0]`?

Comment: @Grundy Все правильно он делает, он же byClassName - получает массив элементов. Его инпут там действительно [0], правда он действительно пустой

Comment: @Mike, читайте по буквам :-) `inp` и `i1`, есть ли разница? :)

Comment: @Grundy Точно, некоторая разница теперь заметна :)

Comment: @Grundy И там действительно значение есть нормальное ...

Comment: Да все верно я выбираю, ipn и i1 это я просто опечатался когда перепечатывал, а значние .value - пусто.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4pQveTxMvGAb

Comment: очередная школота хочет поломать танчики, расходимся пацаны)
Что за бред ты написал?

Comment: @user197892, в какой момент выполняется ваш код?

Comment: Я просто открываю консоль браузера и пытаюсь втулить туда значение инпуту, но если я через .value вписываю, мне пшиет что форма пуста...